# how can read data from excel file inside cell html code in php

Tags: php, html, import-from-excel

ı have a pruduct list for excell

excell look like this

```
 a colum is pruduct code
 b colum is pruduct name
 c colum is description but this cell inside to html code
```

look like this

```
<p style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.6;">ürün açıklamaları </span></p>

<p style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"></p>
<p style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.7999992370605px;"></p>
<div>
<p style="&quot;text-align:"></p>
</div>
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

ı found and use that php code

```
 $exurunacıklama=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
 echo " hücre: ".$exurunacıklama."</br>";
```

but this code not give to me html code

only give to me

```
ürün açıklamaları
```

how to take the html code for excell cels

thanks for helping

Comment: you don't have excel. you have html.

Comment: no ı have a excell inside the cell html code

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this : https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ , might be useful

Comment: have you installed the library ? what error do you get ?

Comment: $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
// Set output Encoding.
$data->setUTFEncoder('iconv'); 
$data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');

Comment: and excell cell write "<div></div>
<div>
<p style=""color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.7999992370605px; text-align: center;""></p>
<p style=""color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, 'Trebuchet MS'; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.7999992370605px;""><span style=""color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.6;"">puroduct description </span></p>

Comment: $exurunacıklama=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]; echo " hücre: ".$exurunacıklama."</br>"; give to me only "puroduct description " but ı need all of them

Comment: hard to understand with such names and without a clear example of your source excel file. What library do you use ??

Answer (score 0):

A good and simple way is to transform excel file in .csv file and fill an array... Use "save as" command on excel, chose .csv and "*" as field separator...below the php code

```
// Open the file .csv
 $data= array();
$filename="data.csv";
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to $data array
if ($fp) {
   $records = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}

$num_rec=count($records);

for($i=0;$i<$num_rec;$i++){
$record=explode("*",$records[$i]);
$data[]=$record;
}
print_r($data);
```